# getting column not allowed error while creating a table

Tags: sql

```
create table school
 (
 empno number(2) not null,
 ename varchar2(10) not null,
 job varchar2(10) default clerk,
 deptno number(3)not null 
 )
```

Comment: 'clerk' instead of clerk

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, this is what you want:

```
create table school (
  empno number(2) not null,
  ename varchar2(10) not null,
  job varchar2(10) default 'clerk',
  deptno number(3) not null 
);
```

`clerk` doesn't mean anything in SQL.